# excel vba runtime error 7 - out of memory

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have two macros in a worksheet. The first one check whether certain cells are addressed and have certain values then runs another macro. The following code is used for this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K10:K1000")) Is Nothing And Target.Value = "Trapezoidal       roof 0.6mm and above" Or Target.Value = "LightBox ballasted" Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call PPAPricePerkWp

End If

End Sub
```

This works fine on it's own.

The second macro is run when a button is clicked. This macro copies and pastes cells/rows to other parts of the spreadsheet.

When the macro is run I get the error `Runtime error 7 - out of memory` and it breaks on the above bit of code.

Is there another way I can check whether cells in a certain column are addressed and have certain values and won't lead to the above error?

Comment: What happens in `PPAPricePerkWp` ?

Comment: It checks a cell value for a cell in column k, does some calculations then pastes a value to the cell below. The debugger breaks at the `If Not Target` line so `PPAPricePerkWp` isn't being run.

Comment: you might want to disable events before you call your subroutine, so that the Worksheet_Change is not being triggered every time you change a cell

Comment: thanks @SeanCheshire that works. I think the second macro was deleting values from a large range of cells so was running out of memory. Do you want to put it as an answer so I can mark it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might want to disable events before you call your subroutine, so that the Worksheet_Change is not being triggered every time you change a cell

`Application.EnableEvents = False`

Don't forget to turn it back on when you are finished